# How to debug a GNUstep application?

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I'm just starting to learn Objective-C using GNUstep on Windows and I'm wondering what type of debugging options are available? I'm using make to compile and link the code, but once I run the app there doesn't appear to be a way to step through code and inspect variables, the call stack or whatever. Now this isn't the end of the world if I could just figure out how to write to standard output in the shell or to some kind of visibile log window, but calling printf and NSDebugLog doesn't seem to work when running a GNUstep application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should most probably use GDB (maybe the MinGW variety), as mentioned in GNUstep [documentation](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/General/Debugging.html).

Note also that GDB has numerous front-ends, which can provide a more pleasant debugging experience. (including Emacs and Eclipse)